# Find if N or more than N records exists between 2 dates. If so update those records without doing extra table scan

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
 ID Name Time Status
 1   A    5     0
 2   B    6     0
 3   C    7     0
 4   D    10    0
```

Lets say N = 2, I need to find whether 2 records exists between time 5 and 10. In this case records with id 2 & 3. If record exists I have to update the status of those records to 1.

Possible Selections. BULK Collect the ids into some temp PLSQL collection and if size of that collection is greater then 2 update the status of those ids.

Is there is any better approach without hitting the table twice?

Comment: What if 3 records exist?  What if 1 exists?

Comment: if N or more than N records found update all the record status to 1. If less than N records found, don't do anything

Comment: It might be simpler to just do the update regardless, and then roll it back it `sql%rowcount` was not 2 or 0.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson . . . That is an interesting suggestion.  You might want to put it in an answer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff good idea - done

Answer (score 2):

In PL/SQL you could do the update regardless and then undo it if `sql%rowcount` is not 2.

```
create or replace procedure p1
    ( p_start date
    , p_end   date )
as
begin
    savepoint before_update;

    update demo set indicator = 'Y'
    where  dt between p_start and p_end
    and    rownum < 4;  -- limit here as we will be rolling back if 3 or more anyway

    dbms_output.put('Updated ' || sql%rowcount || ' row(s)');

    if sql%rowcount <> 2 then
        rollback to before_update;
        dbms_output.put_line(' but rolled back');
    else
        dbms_output.new_line;
    end if;
end p1;
```

Demo (Oracle 12.1):

```
create table demo (dt date not null, indicator varchar2(1));

insert all
    into demo values (date '2018-01-01', null)
    into demo values (date '2018-02-01', null)
    into demo values (date '2018-03-01', null)
    into demo values (date '2018-03-09', null)
    into demo values (date '2018-04-01', null)
    into demo values (date '2018-05-01', null)
select * from dual;


call p1(date '2018-01-01', date '2018-06-01');
-- Updated 3 row(s) but rolled back

call p1(date '2018-03-01', date '2018-03-31');
-- Updated 2 row(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `merge` here:

```
merge into tbl 
  using (select id, count(1) over () cnt from tbl where 5 < time and time < 10) src
  on (tbl.id = src.id and cnt >= 2)
  when matched then update set status = 1;
```

.. or if you prefer PLSQL and `bulk collect` for some reason:

```
declare 
    v_ids sys.odcinumberlist;
begin 
    select id
      bulk collect into v_ids
      from (select id, count(1) over () cnt from tbl where 5 < time and time < 10)
      where cnt >= 2;

    forall i in 1..v_ids.count
      update tbl set status = 1 where id = v_ids(i);
end;
```

Sample data:

```
create table tbl(id, name, time, status) as 
    select 1, 'A',  5, 0 from dual union all
    select 2, 'B',  6, 0 from dual union all
    select 3, 'C',  7, 0 from dual union all
    select 4, 'D', 10, 0 from dual;
```

Result after `merge` or executing block:

```
    ID NAME       TIME     STATUS
------ ---- ---------- ----------
     1 A             5          0
     2 B             6          1
     3 C             7          1
     4 D            10          0
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a strange requirement (to me).  But you can do this using a subquery in the `where` clause:

```
update t
    set status = 1
    where t.time > 5 and t.time < 10 and
          (select count(*) from t where t.time > 5 and t.time < 10) >= 2
```

Comment: This involved hitting table t twice once for calculating the count and then once for updating the table, if i am not wrong. Is there is any way to do this in 1 scan.

Comment: @Dhakchianandan . . . If that is a concern, then an index on `time` should help.  If you have a small table, then this is probably not an issue.